# How to move shiny datatable buttons in sidebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shiny, datatables, dt

I want to move the data table export buttons, i.e. "copy", "excel", "pdf" and "csv", from the table to the shinydashboard sidebar, but I can't get it working.

[image: My aim]

Could someone please help me with this problem and explain to me what I am doing wrong?

**Shiny code**

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- 
   shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
      shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(),
      shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
         shinydashboard::menuItem(
           tabName = NULL,
           icon = shiny::icon("download"),
           text = "Export data set"
         ),
         shiny::tags$div(
           id = "sidebar-table-buttons"  # necessary to reference to in javascript function
         )
      ),
      shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
         shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
         shiny::tags$head(
            shiny::includeScript("www/funcs.js")
         ),
         shiny::fluidRow(
           shinydashboardPlus::box(
              DT::dataTableOutput("dt_mtcars"),
              width = 12,
              height = 12
           )
         )
      )
   )

server <- 
   function(input, output, session) {  
      output$dt_mtcars =
         DT::renderDataTable(
            DT::datatable(
               mtcars,
               selection = "single",
               editable = FALSE,
               #extensions = "Buttons",
               options = list(#dom = "Bt",
                              #buttons = c("copy", "excel", "pdf", "csv")
                              paging = TRUE
               )
            ),
            server = FALSE
         )
   }

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Javascript code in the www/funcs.js file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#dt_mtcars").DataTable({
      responsive: true,
      dom: "Bfrtip",
      buttons: [
         "copy",
         "excel",
         "pdf",
         "csv"
      ]
   });

   $("dt_mtcars_wrapper > .dt-buttons").appendTo("#sidebar-table-buttons");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$div(id = "mybuttons")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      br(), br(),
      DTOutput("dtable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris,
      extensions = "Buttons",
      options = list(
        dom = "Bt",
        buttons = list("copy", "excel")
      ),
      callback = JS("$('#mybuttons').append($('div.dt-buttons'));")
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```